# lowest amount below the average amoutn in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the lowest amount below an average in SQL

I have amount 2000, 2500, 3000.   The average is 2500.

I want to build an SQL query to calculate the AVG and to extract the lowest amount from it.

SELECT AVG(Amount) FROM CONTRACT....

I can't figure out how to do the rest

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are concerned only about the amount field and that the data is not very huge you could try this out -

SELECT MIN(AMOUNT) FROM CONTRACT 
WHERE AMOUNT <= (SELECT AVG(AMOUNT) FROM CONTRACT)

But, wouldn't the lowest amount below average would simply be the lowest amount of all? Something like this -

SELECT MIN(AMOUNT) FROM CONTRACT

Comment: I want the lowest amount below the average amount.  in this case the lowest amount below 2500 is the amount 2000.   The answer seems to be SELECT MIN(Amount)
FROM Contract
WHERE Amount <= (Select AVG(Amount) FROM Contract)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is simply:

```
SELECT MIN(Amount) FROM Contract
```

But your question implies somehow applying AVG to a subset of your data, which I don't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean *subtract* the lowest amount from the average? If so, that'd be

```
SELECT AVG(Amount) - MIN(Amount) FROM CONTRACT...
```